# Strategy to update Node.js and npm

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

We are currently using, `npm` - 9.1.3 and `node` - v16.14.2
What's a good strategy to update both the `npm` and `node` to the latest versions in the Windows environment?

Are there any issues involved?

My `package.json` looks like,

```
{
  "name": "myreact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose --colors",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci --watchAll=false --colors --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --coverage --coverageReporters=cobertura --coverageThreshold '{}'",
    "test:coverage": "jest --verbose --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --verbose --watch",
    "test-debug": "node --inspect-brk --inspect ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest -i",
    "start": "concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --mode development --open\" \"npm:stubby\"",
    "start:iis": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --iis",
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --progress --mode production --dev",
    "build:prod": "lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --format codeframe --ext mjs,jsx,js src",
    "add-locale": "lingui add-locale",
    "extract": "lingui extract",
    "compile": "lingui compile",
    "stubby": "stubby --data stubs/stubby.yaml --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@craftjs/core": "0.2.0-beta.1",
    "@craftjs/utils": "0.2.0-beta.1",
    "@my/react-homegrown": "file:..//thirdparty/react/@my/my-react-homegrown-0.10.90.tgz",
    "@lingui/core": "^2.9.1",
    "@lingui/macro": "^2.9.1",
    "@lingui/react": "^2.9.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.12.8",
    "antlr4": "4.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.26",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "immer": "^9.0.12",
    "json5": "^2.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.32",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pubsub-js": "^1.9.2",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-container-query": "^0.12.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.16.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-resize-detector": "^6.7.2",
    "react-resize-panel": "^0.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.7",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.5",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "recoil": "^0.7.0",
    "resolve": "^1.22.1",
    "sanitize-html": "2.7.1",
    "sheetjs-style": "^0.15.8",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.7",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@lingui/cli": "^2.9.2",
    "@neutrinojs/airbnb": "^9.2.0",
    "@neutrinojs/compile-loader": "^9.2.0",
    "@neutrinojs/dev-server": "^9.4.0",
    "@neutrinojs/eslint": "^9.2.0",
    "@neutrinojs/jest": "^9.2.0",
    "@neutrinojs/react": "^9.2.0",
    "@tippyjs/react": "^4.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^2.8.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.6",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "12.1.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "neutrino": "^9.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.7.1",
    "react-overlays": "^1.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "stubby": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your project dependencies (package.json)? Or do you want more of a generalized response?

Comment: Added it, but a more generalized response is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading dependencies always comes with the risk of causing breakage to older dependencies. Typically, that occurs when you're using a really old module that requires one of your other modules to be on an older version as you go to upgrade it.

One really neat way to find outdated packages comes built-into `NPM`. Try running this in your both your backend and frontend projects:

`npm outdated`

It will return a list that's likely very large of outdated packages. Go through each package and try to find the ones with the largest disparity between the `Current` and `Latest` version. These packages will be the most difficult to upgrade. Also the packages that have a very small difference between current and latest means they are likely outdated. You'll want to check their `Github` repository to see when the last `commit` was and generally if it's being maintained anymore.

Upgrading past `Node 16` is likely to cause breaking changes in your app on the backend. In terms of your front-end and the compiled client, it's not going to have much effect. Upgrading from `React 16` to `18` has many breaking changes though. Migrating from `Material-UI v4` to `v5` has many breaking changes. Also moving from `react-scripts 4` to `5` has quite a few changes.

In general, you'll want to go through all your packages and do some research based on the business needs. It's common for businesses to have to make the touch choice between keeping an older module pegged for awhile before upgrading it, as it may cause a required refactor.

Comment: I came across https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows. Have you used it?

Comment: Yes, I use `nvm` on Mac. I've used `Homebrew` but find `nvm` to be much simpler with one-liner ability to switch versions. I'm mostly in Node 16 but gravitating towards 18 now.

Comment: Did you keep both versions of Node after updating it using nvm-windows? I am reading a few people who got errors while updating the global packages after updating the node version.

Comment: You mean having multiple node versions (`nvm list`)? No, I haven't had issues switching between versions 12,14,16,17. I suppose that could be possible though.

Comment: Yeah, like I want to update to 18 but keep 16. and then I want to update all my packages to 18 as well. Is it possible to keep those packages with 18 as well as 16? I was looking at this https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing Is it available with nvm-windows as well?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible in `nvm-windows`. Someone requested the `--reinstall-packages` feature for `nvm-windows` which is what you're referencing but it appears that was not implemented https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/721 and the issue was closed.

Comment: Do you uninstall the Node installed on windows, after you install node versions using nvm?

Comment: I would uninstall non-nvm managed Node versions before dealing with them but it shouldn't matter.